# Changing domain name from localhost to custom name in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, localhost, domain-name

I am new to MVC and I just created one MVC4 test project in VS 2010, it runs perectly but the url is http://localhost:60826/ I wanted to change it to http://my.test.site or at least http://my.test.site:60826/

I thought I can achieve that by simply putting an entry in host file which will resolve my.test.site to 127.0.0.1 and then just change the url to http://my.test.site:60826 . However it is not working, Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
I was able to achieve this by just adding the 'my.test.site' in proxy ignore list under Internet Options-> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Advanced -> Exception list. now I can access http://my.test.site:60826/ from browser. (Just in case if you want VS to launch the page as http://my.test.site:60826/, go to project-properties-web-start URL add your url there).

Now next step is to get rid of this port number(60826), can anyone throw any light on how to run my application as 'http://my.test.site' i.e. with out any port number?

Answer (score 5):

Are you using IIS or IIS Express?  If the latter, you need to modify the IIS Project URL.

1. Right click your web project
2. Select **Properties**
3. In the **Properties** window, select the **Web** tab.
4. Provide the **Project URL**: `http://localhost:60826/`
5. Provide the Override application root Url: `http://my.test.site:60826/`
6. Click Create Virtual Directory (You may need to be running as Administrator) to do this.
7. Open up: `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`
8. In the  node modify your site to look like the following:

   ```
   <site name="SitenameHere" id="11">
       <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
           <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\**usernameHere**\PathToProjectHere" />
       </application>
       <bindings>
           <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:60826:localhost" />
       </bindings>
   </site>
   ```

Comment: apologeis for my ignorance, how to tell if I am using IIS or IIS Express? btw I can see "Internet Informsation Services (IIS) Manager" in programs and I also check it is version 6.1 but still I am not sure if it is IIS or IIS Express.

Comment: open your project properties, and go tot he web tab, see if Servers section has IIS Express, or LOCAL IIS set.

Comment: it is "Use Local IIS Web Server" in web tab of project properties. Moreover step 5 above to create virtual directory is failing and I am getting "Unable to create virtual directory. Could not find the server 'http://localhost:60825/' on the local machine. Creating a virtual directory is only supported on the local IIS server" (Note: I am running VS as admin as you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running .NET 6.0 Core, the steps to do this are quite different. `Project Properties -> Debug -> General -> Open debug launch profiles UI -> App URL`