# Hosts Redirect 400 Error Web Page Cannot be Found

Tags: c#, iis-express, hosts-file

I'm trying to test my application against the OAuth Microsoft Account Login.

I have added the following to my hosts file

> 127.0.0.1 testdomain.co.uk

My application is running over https so when I run the app it runs as follows;

> https://localhost:44308/home

Now when I hack the url to be

> https://testdomain.co.uk:44308/home

I get the certificate warning (which is to be expected). However, when I click continue to site, i get a 400 Web Page cannot be found error?

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: A screen shot of that 400 error page should tell a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your web server that it should handle the testdomain.co.uk for this project. Your web server (IIS Express) does not know it, as by default it is set to handle "localhost" host only. How to change that is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32365556/3835864